# getting the correct record in Angular with a json feed and passed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

so I have an angular service that picks up a json feed of data, lets say a list of football players - this is working fine. I have a home controller that passes this data through to the home view with code like this...

Home Controller

```js
.controller("mainController", function ($scope, playerService)
    {
      
      var promise = playerService.getPlayers();
      promise.then(function (data)
      {
       
       $scope.players = data;
      });
     
    })
```

Home View

```html
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Club </th>
      <th>More?</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="player in players">
      <td>{{player.name}}</td>
      <td>{{player.club}}&#8457;</td>
      <td><a href="#playercode/{{player.code}}">more</a></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

As you can see from this the id is then pushed to the next page in the URL

here would be the start of the second controller

```js
var promise = playerService.getPlayers();
 promise.then(function (data)
 {
  
  var code = $routeParams.code;
  
  $scope.players = data;
  $scope.whichResult = $routeParams.code;
   
   console.log($scope.players);
   console.log($scope.whichResult);
   
 });
```

What I need to do now is go through the result from the last data set and just pust to the view the data i need but I am not sure how to do this.

I have the date set in $scope.players and the player code in $scope.whichResult but how do i filter just to get the player I want?

I have 2 main routes setup using ngRoute

```js
var playerApp = angular.module('playerApp', ['ngRoute']);
 

playerApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
 
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
     templateUrl : 'app/views/home/homeview.html',
     controller  : 'mainController'
    })
 
    // route for the about page
    .when('/playercode/:code', {
     templateUrl : 'app/views/player/playerview.html',
     controller  : 'playerController'
    })
 
    
  });
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: why use `jQuery`? is there any problem using `$routeParams`? find more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: i dont know how to do in Angular - I am trying to learn :) @maddog (Can you provide some sample code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby

// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

Reference: [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

For creating a URL, you can use `$location` e.g.:

```
$location.path('/chapter/' + Id + '/section/' + secId);
```

Comment: hi @maddog i am now using routeParams as you said and I have updated my question. Thanks for the help so far